# Efficient Overlapped I/O for a socket server

Tags: windows, sockets, visual-c++, performance, io-completion-ports

Which of these two different models would be more efficient (consider thrashing, utilization of processor cache, overall desgn, everything, etc)?

1. 1 IOCP and spinning up X threads (where X is the number of processors the computer has). This would mean that my "server" would only have 1 IOCP (queue) for all requests and X Threads to serve/handle them. I have read many articles discussing the effeciency of this design. With this model I would have 1 listener that would also be associated to the IOCP. Lets assume that I could figure out how to keep the packets/requests synchronized.
2. X IOCP (where X is the number of processors the computer has) and each IOCP has 1 thread. This would mean that each Processor has its own queue and 1 thread to serve/handle them. With this model I would have a separate Listener (not using IOCP) that would handle incomming connections and would assign the SOCKET to the proper IOCP (one of the X that were created). Lets assume that I could figure out the Load Balancing.

Using an overly simplified analogy for the two designs (a bank):

1. One line with several cashiers to hand the transactions. Each person is in the same line and each cashier takes the next available person in line.
2. Each cashier has their own line and the people are "placed" into one of those lines

Between these two designs, which one is more efficient. In each model the Overlapped I/O structures would be using VirtualAlloc with MEM_COMMIT (as opposed to "new") so the swap-file should not be an issue (no paging). Based on how it has been described to me, using VirtualAlloc with MEM_COMMIT, the memory is reserved and is not paged out. This would allow the SOCKETS to write the incomming data right to my buffers without going through intermediate layers. So I don't think thrashing should be a factor but I might be wrong.

Someone was telling me that #2 would be more efficient but I have not heard of this model. Thanks in advance for your comments!

Comment: I'm not sure, but does #2 even work? Is it possible to listen on the same socket by several different threads?

Comment: yes, it is possible. At least, on unix, I'm sure windows is not different at it

Comment: what I would do is have a separate Listener object that listened for incomming connections. That object would assign the SOCKET to one of the IOCP. Each IOCP would not listen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that for #2 you plan to manually associate your sockets with an IOCP that you decide is 'best' based on some measure of 'goodness' at the time the socket is accepted? And that somehow this measure of 'goodness' will persist for the life of the socket?

With IOCP used the 'standard' way, i.e. your option number 1, the kernel works out how best to use the threads you have and allows more to run if any of them block. With your method, assuming you somehow work out how to distribute the work, you are going to end up with more threads running than with option 1.

Your #2 option also prevents you from using `AcceptEx()` for overlapped accepts and this is more efficient than using a normal accept loop as you remove a thread (and the resulting context switching and potential contention) from the scene.

Your analogy breaks down; it's actually more a case of either having 1 queue with X bank tellers where you join the queue and know that you'll be seen in an efficient order as opposed to each teller having their own queue and you having to guess that the queue you join doesn't contain a whole bunch of people who want to open new accounts and the one next to you contains a whole bunch of people who only want to do some paying in. The single queue ensures that you get handled efficiently.

I think you're confused about `MEM_COMMIT`. It doesn't mean that the memory isn't in the paging file and wont be paged. The usual reason for using `VirtualAlloc` for overlapped buffers is to ensure alignment on page boundaries and so reduce the number of pages that are locked for I/O (a page sized buffer can be allocated on a page boundary and so only take one page rather than happening to span two due to the memory manager deciding to use a block that doesn't start on a page boundary).

In general I think you're attempting to optimise something way ahead of schedule. Get an efficient server working using IOCP the normal way first and then profile it. I seriously doubt that you'll even need to worry about building your #2 version ... Likewise, use `new` to allocate your buffers to start with and then switch to the added complexity of `VirtualAlloc()` when you find that you server fails due to `ENOBUFS` and you're sure that's caused by the I/O locked page limit and not lack of non-paged pool (you do realise that you have to allocate in 'allocation granularity' sized chunks for `VirtualAlloc()`?).

Anyway, I have a free IOCP server framework that's available here: http://www.serverframework.com/products---the-free-framework.html which might help you get started.

**Edited:** The complex version that you suggest could be useful in some NUMA architectures where you use NIC teaming to have the switch spit your traffic across multiple NICs,  bind each NIC to a different physical processor and then bind your IOCP threads to the same processor. You then allocate memory from that NUMA node and effectively have your network switch load balance your connections across your NUMA nodes. I'd still suggest that it's better, IMHO, to get a working server which you can profile using the "normal" method of using IOCP first and only once you know that cross NUMA node issues are actually affecting your performance move towards the more complex architecture...

Comment: Hey Len, yes I have seen your free code (and still reviewing it actually). You have a free version and a licensed version right? Thanks for the clarification on MEM_COMMIT. That is how it was described to me by the person that was promoting #2. I am also aware of the page boundary allocation with VirtualAlloc. Also, yes I would use a thread to wait for new connections (with #2) and would associate the SOCKET to the IOCP which would stick for the duration of the connection. I would actually use AcceptEx and set the hEvent of the OVERLAPPED struct. (if I am not mistaken)

Comment: I believe you mentioned somewhere that your free version doesn't work well when multiple are ran on the same server (ie one for port 443 and another for port 993, etc). That is a situation that might happen for us.

Comment: You don't need to use the `hEvent` in the `OVERLAPPED` with IOCP. #2 is wrong; simple as that, it wont perform as well as #1. The free code is less resource efficient for multiple servers but they still work just fine.

Comment: Yes, I meant that I would use the hEvent if the listener was separate from the IOCP (needed with #2). If used with the IOCP the hEvent is not needed. Sorry for the confusion. Thanks for the confirmation that #2 is less efficient. I was assuming it was but wanted a sanity check. The particular person that I was talking to was not someone I could easily disagree with at work. ;) I will continue to check out your free solution. Thanks again for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

Queuing theory tells us that a single queue has better characteristics than multiple queues.  You could possibly get around this with work-stealing.

The multiple queues method should have better cache behavior.  Whether it is significantly better depends on how many received packets are associated with a single transaction.  If a request fits in a single incoming packet, then it'll be associated to a single thread even with the single IOCP approach.